# Exclamation after tricking someone

Tags: expressions

What is the right exclamation for expressing schadenfreude and revealing the banter after tricking someone? In German there is the phrase "Reingelegt!". In my opinion "Just kidding!" lacks of schadenfreude.

Comment: ["Gotcha!"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gotcha), perhaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think **Gotcha!** carries the impression you're looking for. Alternatives might include "Made you look!" or "Had you going!", but **Gotcha!** I think is the closest.

Comment: Suck it. Burn! Zing! Oh, that's gotta sting. (tone counts, of course)